# Updating a local gem with c extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've cloned a gem from github and using it locally by providing local path in Gemfile.

```
gem 'abc' , path: 'path/to/abc'
```

The gem has c extension that I want to make some changes to. I made changes in a file located at ext/my_file.c and ran the bundle install command. The changes are not reflecting. What else should I do to reflect the changes?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You must have built the extensions somehow when you first used the gem (maybe with `rake build` or similar). You’ll need to rebuild it to see the changes – currently it will be using the previous compiled library.

Comment: I just cloned it and started using it without executing any command. It works but new changes are not reflecting. Should I try rake build

Comment: [Using `:path` in the `Gemfile` doesn’t compile any extensions](http://bundler.io/v1.11/man/gemfile.5.html#PATH-path-), so I don’t understand how it’s working at all, maybe there is a pure Ruby fallback implementation. Can you give a link to the actual repository?

Comment: https://github.com/reidmorrison/rubywmq

Comment: Looking at the repository, I can’t see how it could be working without some build step. Are you using `bundle exec ...` when running your code?

Comment: No, if I try rake build would it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109168/discussion-between-arif-and-matt).